# Is it possible to use 'enable_if' and 'is_same' with variadic function templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, enable-if

These two non-variadic function templates do compile:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, int>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U b) {
    std::cout << "b is integer\n";
}

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, float>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U b) {
    std::cout << "b is float\n";
}
```

however, similar variadic templates do not compile:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, int>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are integers\n";
}

template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, float>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are floats\n";
}
```

Maybe I am trying to do something that cannot be done. I know that similar functionality can be achieved using initializer lists, but I would like to avoid curly brackets required for initializer list arguments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. You can use a [*fold expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) in C++17:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same<U, float>::value && ...), void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are floats\n";
}
```

In C++11, you can reimplement [`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction):

```
template<class...> struct conjunction : std::true_type { };
template<class B1> struct conjunction<B1> : B1 { };
template<class B1, class... Bn>
struct conjunction<B1, Bn...> 
    : std::conditional_t<bool(B1::value), conjunction<Bn...>, B1> {};
```

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<U, float>...>, 
    void
>::type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are floats\n";
}
```

Comment: + for the C++17 fold expression

Comment: Fold expressions are bugged in VS2017 as of 15.7.5, so the alternate solution is necessary, minus the reimplementation of `std::conjunction`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo The example using `std::conjunction` has a slight bug - `::value` is already taken by `conjunction`. I.e., it should be `enable_if<conjunction_v<is_same<U, float>...>, void>`

Comment: How would this work if I can't use a return type? For constructors for example?

Comment: @katrasnikj: it doesn't matter where this is, as long as it's part of the signature. It can be a default template parameter or default function parameter.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo ah yes, I see. I was having problems with the fold expression version. It works with `std::conjuction`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could simply make use of additional variadic `pack` to test if all template arguments are the same and equal to a given type (C++11):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class...>
struct pack { };

template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<pack<int, U...>, pack<U..., int>>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are integers\n";
}

template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<pack<float, U...>, pack<U..., float>>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are floats\n";
}

int main() {
    testFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    testFunction(1, 2.0f, 3.5f, 4.4f, 5.3f);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sOHMuGRJ96P59EmE)

Output:

```
bs are integers
bs are floats
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are bound to C++ 11 and want to keep your code readable, you can implement simple equivalent of `is_same` which matches multiple types:

```
template <typename Ref, typename T1, typename... TN>
struct all_match;

template <typename Ref, typename T>
struct all_match<Ref,T>
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T,Ref>::value;
};

template <typename Ref, typename T1, typename... TN>
struct all_match
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<T1,Ref>::value && all_match<Ref, TN...>::value;
};
```

And then (note, that the reference type goes first):

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<all_match<int, U...>::value, void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are integers\n";
}
```

Live demo: [click](https://ideone.com/5XSfsl).

C++ 17 introduces [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) which allows you to fold parameter pack (`...`) over a binary operator. You can use it to easy apply `std::is_same<>` for all types in a parameter pack and then `and` the values:

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same<U, float>::value && ...), void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are floats\n";
}

template <typename T, typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same<U, int>::value && ...), void>::
type testFunction(T a, U... bs) {
    std::cout << "bs are ints\n";
}
```

You can check demo for this version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89a954ada5e1517a).