# Variadic functions and fold expression: Fatal Error while trying to compile in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I was reading this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48764158/1757805) and some of the answers provided a possible solution for using Fold Expressions in C++17. I thought I'd try this technique within my own code.

This is what I have tried:

**Some Header**

```
#pragma once

#include <bitset>
#include <type_traits>

using Bit = std::bitset<1>;

template<typename... Bits>
typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same<Bits, Bit>::value && ...), Bit>::type
And(Bits... bits) {
    return (bits&...);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Some Header"

int main()
{   
    Bit b1_0{0};
    Bit b1_1{1};
    Bit b2_0{0};
    Bit b2_1{1};

    // Intended uses:
    Bit res1 = And(b1_0, b1_1, b2_0); // res1 should = 0
    Bit res2 = And(b1_1, b2_1); // res2 should = 1

    std::cout << "res1 = " << res1.to_string() << '\n';
    std::cout << "res2 = " << res2.to_string() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017; and this fails to compile I am getting a `"fatal error C1001"`.

I don't know if it is coming from the fold expression or if how I am trying to apply the repeated `&` on each `Bit` that is passed into the function etc.

When I try this using Compiler Explorer: [goldbot](https://godbolt.org/z/LX15TK) It compiles fine using either GCC or Clang but fails in Visual Studio...

How would I be able to do something similar to this that works in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with goldbot seems that your code compile starting from MSVC v19.21.

I don't understand what wrong before; anyway, passing through a `constexpr` function as follows

```
template <typename ... Bits>
constexpr bool all_bits ()
{ return (std::is_same_v<Bits, Bit> && ...);  }

template<typename... Bits>
std::enable_if_t<all_bits<Bits...>(), Bit>
 And(Bits... bits) {
    return (bits & ...);
}
```

seems to works also with v19.20 and older versions.

Comment: Excellent; visual studio does have support for the fold expressions but the syntax is quite different of that from GCC or Clang. It appears that Visual Studio requires the helper template to be able to parse the source code where GCC and Clang doesn't need it.